# How do I find contour integral with no poles?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to know if the contour integral have no poles how do I solve it? Please explain with workings. Thank you.

$\displaystyle\oint_C z^5 \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z^2}\right) \space dz$

Comment: What happens at $z = 0$ ?

Comment: And where is your contour ?

Comment: At (0,1) is my contour

Comment: "Contour" means simple closed curve, in this case.  So $(0,1)$ won't help if it is supposed to be a contour integral.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that you are integrating a simple closed contour that includes the origin.  By the residue theorem, the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles or other isolated singularities inside the integration contour (times a winding number).  The residue is the coefficient of $1/z$ in the Laurent expansion of the integrand.  So:

$$\sin{\frac1{z^2}} = \frac1{z^2} - \frac1{6 z^6} + \cdots...$$

The coeffficient of $1/z$ in the integrand then is $-1/6$; thus, the integral is $-i \pi/3$.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the residue theorem applies here since $\sin(1/z^2)$ isn't meromorphic near $z = 0$.  Can it be used in this case?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: well, we do compute residues at infinity where entire functions like sine and exp are not really meromorphic. One could transform this problem by letting $\zeta=1/z$ and finding such a residue at infinity; the result is the same.  So, long answer, yes this is OK.

Comment: You're right of course -- it looks like the version of the theorem I was referencing was unnecessarily restrictive.  The part of the proof I was stumbling over was the interchange of the series and the integral, but the Laurent series converges uniformly so there's nothing to worry about.  Cheers.

Comment: Technically we are dealing with an isolated essential singularity, not a pole.

Comment: @RandomVariable: that is correct.